# Is it possible to use bootstrap for adobe flex?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, apache-flex, mxml

I am trying to get my application looking somewhat decent and flex uses CSS so does that mean I can use bootstrap? I just don't know how I would implement it in the code once I have the CSS as mxml is different to html. If not, are there any other frameworks I can use to get my application looking better?

Answer (score 0):

No; Bootstrap requires javascript (not available inside the Flex app).  Also, Flex uses its own [customized subset](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf62883-7ff2.html#WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf62883-7fef) of CSS with some important differences from the spec.